# GNU Parallel: how to pass job id to command

Tags: gnu-parallel

Suppose I am running gnu parallel on an array of items received from standard in, and split according to some criteria:

```
cat content | parallel -j 4 my_command
```

How do I access the job number such that I can pass into command, as an argument, the job number/id of the parallel execution (so that each parallel execution block has a unique number):

```
cat content | parallel -j 4 my_command -n ???
```

(Is this even possible? Reviewing the man pages at the moment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the replacement string `{#}`

```
cat content | parallel -j 4 my_command -n {#}
```

It is also mentioned on the cheat sheet: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf

Comment: Please add some more explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it - what have you changed and why?

Comment: How do I access the job number sent in by this, in my code inside my_command?

Comment: @GeoffreyAnderson You access that as you would any other argument (argv).